# SystemConfiguration.framework appears red

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I am writing the Network detection stuff for my app but when I go to Link Binary with Libraries and add SystemConfiguration.framework it appears red, and my app breaks. Has anyone got any ideas on why it might be doing this and how I can solve it?

Comment: I think u mightnot have added the freamework properly. If make it drag and drop, make checkmark true for copying it and if added then it may be deleted from its actual place....:)

Comment: try right-clicking it and click show in finder.. it's possible that you'd accidently deleted it sometime (i.e. you were deleting it from another project by clicking 'delete' instead of 'remove reference'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have deleted it from your project by accident I have done this in the past when you delete you must have move to trash instead of remove reference, I had to download xcode again to get it back.

Comment: It works also if you find a copy of the framework from the same SDK - had the same problem :)

Comment: @rokjarc comment seems a lot simpler then mine would recommend do it this way before attempting my way.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a case of either the Framework simply not being added to the project properly, or, worst case, as it has been suggested here, you could have deleted the framework itself from your Mac altogether.

Here a few things you can try out,

- Does the framework not appear at all on the project navigator in XCode? Or does it appear red? In either case, go to the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section in your Target summary, and click the '+' button to try and add the framework.
- If the framework exists in this list, no problem, simply add it again, and you should be all good.
- If its not there at ALL, then this looks like you may have deleted the framework from you machine altogether. If so, you can either reinstall XCode, or you could simply get that framework folder from a colleagues machine and drop it in the frameworks folder.